# How to make use of str library functions to pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I would like to know how str module functions can directly be applied to pydatatable Dataframe without explicitly being converted to a pandas DataFrame.

Sample DT:

```
DT_py = dt.Frame (
{ 'ciudad':['PERTH','SYDNEY','PORT','MELBOURNE','DARWIN'],
'pop' : [320,433,121,423,212]
})
```

I'm now trying to capitalize a field: ciudad with the help of str module as follow

```
DT_py[“ciudad“]= DT_py[:,f.ciudad].to_pandas().ciudad.str.capitalize()
```

Is there any pydatatable way to get it done?.

Are the datatable Frames supporting str modules yet?.

Comment: There are very few string functions currently available, but the roadmap for the next version suggests that more will be added soon: https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/2281

Comment: This roadmap task together with the Windows build are my most expected features of pydatatable!

Comment: Ok guys, got it and thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

As per H2O team plan, the required string manipulation functionalities will be added in data table 0.11 version onward.